# jquery input detect value change

Tags: jquery

I downloaded a calendar from the web. This one: http://www.codeanddesign-studio.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Date-Range-Picker.gif

Calendar works great, now I want to check everytime that the input box change value, user has only 2 options type the date or select the date from the calendar.

I can detect everytime user type something doing this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#inputA').daterangepicker().bind('change',function() {
       valA=$(this).val() ;
    });
});
```

But when user select a date from the calendar doesn't detect the change.
I was thinking in using a setInterval and check the input every X time not sure how to do that or if that is the right solution. What are your recommendations?

Comment: Does the plugin you are using have any options or events? You should provide a link to the plugin's website, rather than an image of what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it is [this](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-UI-Date-Range-Picker) one in which case you do,

```
$(function(){
    $('#inputA').daterangepicker({
      onChange: function() {
        valA = $(this).val();
      }
    });
});
```